# Override root path in ReactJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, package.json, npm-start

When I run my application using `npm start`, it runs on the root

```
You can now view my-app in the browser.

  Local:            http://localhost:3000/
```

I want to change it so it hits index.html using `http://localhost:3000/my-app` and doesn't directly deploy on the root.

I tried adding the `homepage` peoperty in `package.json` but it still runs on the root.

```
..
"homepage": "https://localhost:3000/my-app",..
```

Comment: have you got any answer for this already?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try changing your `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` to point to your `my-app` directory? The relevant code I see for determining the public url location on `react` is the following:

```
const envPublicUrl = process.env.PUBLIC_URL;

...

const getPublicUrl = appPackageJson =>
  envPublicUrl || require(appPackageJson).homepage;
```

So if your `process.env.PUBLIC_URL;` is already set, by **short-circuit evaluation**, your second conditional statement: `require(appPackageJson).homepage;` will not be evaluated. So perhaps your `homepage` key is not even being evaluated from within your `package.json` file. For more information on setting/getting  node's `process.env` variables check out this [tutorial](https://codeburst.io/process-env-what-it-is-and-why-when-how-to-use-it-effectively-505d0b2831e7)

Hopefully that helps!